# Server hard drive crash, need a way to retrieve database meta data

Tags: data-recovery

My development server hard drive crashed and i was running Microsoft sql server on it as my database. I was wondering if its possible to export the databases or copy the meta data? the only way i can see the files is through a live boot linux cd so where is the database files located on disk?

Comment: Just restore from backup. You know, the copy of the important data that you make frequently so that you aren't relying on a single hard disk (which any system administrator knows are prone to failure over time).

Comment: alternatively McDonalds is waiting ;) Serving burgers does not require backups.

Answer (score 1):

If you can mount the file system and navigate across the directory structure, then there is a chance that you can rescue things. Some steps to consider:

1. Backing up the partition to another drive (GParted or any other partition utility)
2. Boot the Windows installation media to a command prompt
3. Run chkdsk against the partition/disk in question

If needed, there may be other 3rd party utilities which can automate the steps as well as include additional functionality to assist.